# Photon Networking - Getroomlist()

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, photon

I used the get room list function for getting the rooms in the server. But once i joined the particular room ,I am not able to see the list? How can i see the list even if i connected to room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to by creating a second instance of `PhotonNetwork` and connecting it to said server where the games are hosted, and have this instance a game object that also talks to the object that has your lobby script. Not to sure if this will work or how hard it would be to implement. I'm currently working with Photon myself.

Comment: this will double the concurrent users, Which i cant afford. :/

Comment: How can i achieve this? Getting two instance of photonnetwork?

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: I'm afraid the answer is you can't - its not supported out of the box.

Long Answer:

## Its per Design

The reason for this is the scalable architecture of Photon Loadbalancing
which is the server side application and part of the sdk that is usually
used in conjuncion with PUN. Loadbalancing is also what is driving the Photon Cloud in case that is what you are refering too.

What happens is that your client initially connects to what is called the Master, where the matchmaking takes place. Your client cn either create a new room or join a room using the list of rooms or any of the other matchmaking options like JoinRandom for instance.

Once any of this happens the master will send your client the information required to connect to the GameServer hosting the game.
In case of a new client it will send your client to the server with least load.

Under load the list of games and their properties can change very quickly
 - games are created
 - players join and leave
 - games can reach their max allowed # of players

this changes are propagated from all the GameServers back to the Master
but it is not propagated to all GameServers, meanig its not available to your client once its in a room.

## Options

There is a longer thread about this topic here:
http://forum.exitgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=3093

The gist is of the discussion is:

- In case you are using the selfhosted version Photon (not the Photon Cloud) you could extend Loadbalancing.
- You could connect a second peer and leave it connected to the master, with the disadantage that it is counted as a second ccu, which might be a problem for your costs since its all based on ccu.

## Disatvantages of Game Lists

In general the use of game lists as design component in the games tends to be overrated - it is an easy way to have matchmaking during devlopment but doesn't work well (for most of the games) when going live.

Players usually don't care and match to games based on filters (there is no need for game lists for that since photon supports matchmaking with filters), usually leading to player choosing one of the first games on the list. Under load this often means that many player try to join the same game, which usually is a problem since most games need some kind of max # of players.
BTW: if they care its often "I wan't to play with a friend", which is also supported by the photon matchmaking.

If you have mobile clients the lists of games can be a burden specially with very active games, it takes a time to load the lists and it uses bandwith to load and mantain them. Due to the latancy its also more likely for players to select games that are already full.